# Why would JAXB generate single List<JAXBElement<String>> field from two fields in the Schema?

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

Why would this Schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ErrType">
<xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 <xsd:element name="errorCode" type="xsd:string"/>
 <xsd:element name="errorDescription" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Generate to this Java code:

```
class ErrType {
  @XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "errorCode", namespace = "http://somewhere/blah.xsd", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "errorDescription", namespace = "http://somewhere/blah.xsd", type = JAXBElement.class)
  })
  protected List<JAXBElement<String>> errorCodeAndErrorDescription;
  // ... 
}
```

I would have expected something more like:

```
class ErrType extends ArrayList<ErrTypeEntry> {}
class ErrTypeEntry {
  protected String errorCode
  protected String errorDescription;
}
```

Okay, so I guess the answer is: because it does. Combining two fields into a single one seems very undesirable. It removed important structure unnecessarily.

Comment: What is the problem with the generated code?  What would you have expected?

Comment: Maybe because you are specifying minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" on sequence element. try to specify them in element.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you'd have to write your schema a bit more like this to get something closer (structurally) to your expectations:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ErrTypeEntry">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="errorCode" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="errorDescription" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Errors">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="error" type="ErrTypeEntry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```